# Return value immediate when subscription to graphql.

Tags: graphql

I have Query that return array of object(Asset), and Subscription that return one object (Asset) each time.

```
type Query {
  assets(assets: [AssetInput!]!): [Asset!]!
}

type Subscription {
  assetSubscription(assets: [AssetInput!]!): Asset!
}
```

The client need to  query assets, and than to subscription to them.

My question is whether it is possible to do it in one query ?